# Oracle sequence repeat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle10g

My application is deployed on different site but with centralized schema with single DB. Problem is I choose sequence not to repeat data in db but we application deployed in multiple site sequence repeat here is my code

```
entryid = objDB.CallSequence("SEQ_RESULTTEST");

var query = "SELECT " + HttpContext.Current.Session["bookcode"] + "." + SQ_NAME + ".nextval from dual";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query.ToUpper(), cn);
string maxcode = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

This entryid contain same value when multiple site access at the same time Please suggest what should I do not to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence in the "centralized DB". Locally, create a synonym for it over a database link. Doing so, all sites will use the same sequence.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create database link dblp 
  2  connect to pek identified by jzv
  3  using 'centralized_db';

Database link created.

SQL> -- does it work?
SQL> select * from dual@dblp;

D
-
X

SQL> -- a synonym 
SQL> create synonym s_seqa for seqa@dblp;

Synonym created.

SQL> select s_seqa.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
5354227730

SQL>
```

Comment: We are using centralized schema so we do not need to create link we directly access sequence from all site. Even I am access to sequence but problem is when 2 user hit same function at the same time sequence.next value for every user is not working. both user got same value

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible to fetch the same sequence value twice. You mentioned a **function**. What *function*? What does it do? Do you use a "real" sequence, an Oracle object? Or do you calculate it using your own code and just *call it* a sequence? Could you post that function's code? If so, edit your initial message.